# Simple MySQL timestamp query fails

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a query that's been running as a daily job that's worked for years. Somehow, it stopped yesterday.

I have a `timestamp` field which has proper values and a query...

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `shoppingcart` 
WHERE  `creation_datetime` like  '2013-06-16'
```

I get back an empty resultset. If I add a `%` after the date it works.

MySQL is 5.1.61, nothing's been updated on the server.

Answer (score 5):

If you only want the `date` part of a `datetime` column you can use [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) to extract it

```
SELECT * 
FROM shoppingcart
WHERE date(creation_datetime) = '2013-06-16'
```

But this won't use indexes as @eggyal mentioned. That is why you should better use

```
SELECT * 
FROM shoppingcart
WHERE creation_datetime >= '2013-06-16' 
AND creation_datetime < '2013-06-17'
```

Answer (score 3):

`datetime` types have dates and times. Always. If you omit the time portion, it's same as using all zero's, and thus would only match records where the time is exactly midnight. This is why `%` is working - because it accepts any time.

Example of datetime: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`

Answer (score 1):

When you use `LIKE`, you have to use `%` signs, otherwise `LIKE` acts same as `=`. Try

```
LIKE  '2013-06-16%'
```

Otherwise you can simply use the DATE function

```
DATE(creation_datetime) = '2013-06-16'
```

Comment: Can you post some of the values stored for `creation_datetime`

Comment: 2013-06-16 02:40:10
2013-06-16 04:19:22
2013-06-16 06:20:40